# Looping through the json service response in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working on a angular project. i have a scenario where i need to list some details in a page of the application.I have a service call in the page which returns the following json structure. i want to loop through this json structure to list few of the data in the response.

```
[
  {
    "ProductDetails": [
      {
        "ProductType": "Application1",
        "Name": "Product1",
        "New": false,
        "Category": "product",
        "Country": "India",
        "description": "Description for Product1",
        "Favourite": false,
        "settings": {
          "WebsiteFlag": true,
          "SmsFlag": false,
          "EmailFlag": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductDetails": [
      {
        "ProductType": "Application2",
        "Name": "Product2",
        "New": true,
        "Category": "product",
        "Country": "India",
        "description": "Description for Product2",
        "Favourite": true,
        "settings": {
          "WebsiteFlag": false,
          "SmsFlag": false,
          "EmailFlag": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**JS**

```
            $ctrl.getSettings = function () {
                var url = "http://localhost:3000/json/settings-updated.json";
                rsicontext.getData(url).then(function (response) {
                    $ctrl.Settings = response.data;
                });
            }
```

**HTML**

```
        <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="app in $ctrl.Settings" class="content-box">
        <td data-ng-bind="app.ProductDetails.ProductType"></td>
        <td data-ng-bind="app.ProductDetails.Name"></td>
        <td><ng-checkbox data-checked="app.SmsFlag" rounded="true"></ng-checkbox></td>
        <td><ng-checkbox data-checked="app.EmailFlag" rounded="true"></ng-checkbox></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I am trying to list the Product Type, Name, EmailFlag and SmsFlag. How can i loop through the json structure to list the data.

Comment: Can `ProductDetails` contain more than a single `ProductDetails` object? If not, why is it an array?

Comment: there is no `SmSFlag` directly located on your `ProductDetails` object. To get the `ng-checkbox` working you need `app.ProductDetails.settings.SmsFlag`

Answer (score 0):

Simply go over the response and build a new array from the fields you need. Like so:

```
var d = [];
for( vari=0;i< response.data.ProductDetails.length; ++i) {
    var curr= {
         ProductType: response.data.ProductDetails[i].ProductType, 
         Name: response.data.ProductDetails[i].Name            
    }
    d.push(curr);
 }

  $ctrl.Settings = d;
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate object or array I always use a library called underscore.js

This can help you to do what you want.

```
var plucked=_.pluck($ctrl.Settings, 'ProductDetails');
```

This function will return an array of object. Then you can loop it.

https://jsfiddle.net/wz2njukj/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this throw `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data[0].ProductDetails[0]">
    {{ d.SmsFlag }} {{ d.WebsiteFlag}} {{d.EmailFlag}} 
</div>
```

Look this and get data as you want.

[PlunkerHere](https://plnkr.co/edit/2kKDEuafV2WbjQXHTneE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`ProductDetails` contains an array, so you would have to nest ngRepeats

```
<span data-ng-repeat="detail in app.ProductDetails">
```

If you know that `ProductDetails` will only have one element it would be best to change the structure that is being generated if you can. If not you can access it in markup

```
   <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="app in $ctrl.Settings" class="content-box">
    <td data-ng-bind="app.ProductDetails[0].ProductType"></td>
    <td data-ng-bind="app.ProductDetails[0].Name"></td>
    <td><ng-checkbox data-checked="app.ProductDetails[0].settings.SmsFlag" rounded="true"></ng-checkbox></td>
    <td><ng-checkbox data-checked="app.ProductDetails[0].settings.EmailFlag" rounded="true"></ng-checkbox></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Or you can massage the data in your controller before passing it off to the view.

```
$ctrl.Settings = response.data.map(products=>products.ProductDetails[0])
```